# Release Management 2015 recommendations

Tags: visual-studio-2015, release-management, ms-release-management

I am going to setup Release Management for Visual Studio 2015.

I have few doubts:

1. What is new with RM for VS 2015 compare to RM for VS 2013 update 4.
2. Which is the recommended way of implementation, vNext or RM with
   deployment agent.

   3. If it is vNext, please share some tutorials to
      learn it.

Experts please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. RM for VS2015 has only improvements: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx#ReleaseManagement
2. The recommendation is to use the vNext templates because it'd be easier to the migrate to the upcoming RM [vNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/release/overview-rmpreview) (or Release Management Service) which is based on the same system as the new build system that is available in TFS2015
3. Basically you need to use PowerShell/DSC or Chef; a good start is [here](http://roadtoalm.com/2015/02/04/start-with-visual-studio-release-management-vnextvs-rm-for-dummies/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please suggest some tutorial to learn RM vNext?